# Function LEAST() does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with SQL LEAST function. This code should take lowest number from column named ORDER in table NAVIGATION (there are only numbers). After that - compare, if the number is(not) egual to zero. If it isn't then the code should set the first record in table column ORDER to 0. It just somehow always return the lowest number as 0 even if theres no 0 in column order. So the condition is always true.

```
 $sql="SELECT LEAST(999,order) FROM navigation";
        $lowest_num = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        if ($lowest_num != 0) {$sql2 = "UPDATE navigation SET order= '0' LIMIT 1";
            mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
        }
```

Comment: You actually want [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min): `SELECT MIN('order') FROM navigation`

Comment: Since `ORDER` is a reserved keyword, I would expect this code not to work at all unless it is enclosed in backticks.

Comment: What do you think [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns upon success?

Comment: Wiat's the datatype of the order-column?

Comment: The datatype of it is integer.

Comment: hm  $lowest_num is actually just returning a resource or false. You would have to have fetch the row and get values to compare... Use for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php (In fact don't use mysql_*-functions at all, but in this case - use it :-))

Comment: It doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  $sql="SELECT MIN(`order`) as lowest FROM navigation";
```

- dont forget to use backticks around ORDER because its [reserved keyword of mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

**AND** change this

```
if ($lowest_num != 0)
```

to

```
 if ( mysql_num_rows($lowest_num) != 0 )
```

**AND** change this

```
 UPDATE navigation SET order
```

to

```
UPDATE navigation SET `order`
```

EDIT:

try this

```
 $sql="SELECT MIN(`order`) as lowest FROM navigation";
    $lowest_num = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($lowest_num) or die (mysql_error());
    if ( mysql_num_rows($lowest_num) != 0 and $row['lowest'] != 0) {$sql2 = "UPDATE navigation SET `order`= '0' LIMIT 1";
        mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: It is great. But I dont know why the condition is always true, always - no matter if there is or isnt zero in ORDER column.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the `MIN()` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min

```
"SELECT MIN(`order`) FROM navigation"
```

This will return the minimum value of the `order` column in the `navigation` table.

[`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) only returns the minimum values from its arguments, and is not an aggregate function.

Comment: Ok, function MIN() is better, however it still passes the condition even if at least one record in order column IS equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

That query will return the least of 999 and order for **each** row. You need to use `"SELECT MIN(order) FROM navigation"`. If you still need to do the least of 999 and this minimum, you can just do:

```
$lowest_num = min(mysql_query($sql), 999) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do these in one step with:

```
UPDATE navigation
    SET order = 0
    where not exists (select * from (select 1 from navigation having min(`order`) = 0))
    LIMIT 1
```

Or, if `order` is never negative:

```
UPDATE navigation
    SET order = 0
    where not exists (select * from (select 1 from navigation where `order` = 0))
    LIMIT 1
```

(As written, this is not necessarily more efficient; it is meant to capture the logic.  You would write this with a `join` for efficiency.)

The `join` form is what you would want to use:

```
update navigation cross join
      (select min(`order`) as minorder from navigation) const
    set navigation.`order` = 0
    where const.minorder = 0
    limit 1;
```

Comment: This causes problem with "read write" in same time in same table ERROR mysql.

Comment: @Croolman . . . You are correct.  I was just showing that it is possible to do in one query, although in MySQL you need an additional level of subqueries for this to work.  The `join` method is better anyway for performance reasons.